# Преобразователь сатоши в биткоин

Tags: php

Задача такая меня постигла, имеем в базе ячейку money тип ячейки bigint туда пишется баланс сатоши, так как различного рода зачисления удобней и проще делать в сатошах (целых числах ежели с плавающей запятой еще и такой дроби) так вот задача такая. Нам нужно вывести баланс с ячейки money но юзеру показать в формате биткоина. То есть скажем не 1000 а 0.00001000 вопрос подскажите на пхп как проще без длинного велосипеда. Спасибо.

Comment: Простое деление работает лишь если сумма большая,если сумма маленькая скажем 1000 сатошей, то возврат такой получается 1.0E-5 что не очень то и корректно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычисления с произвольной точностью c помощью библиотеки BCMath
[ссылка на документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php)

```
$sat = 1000;
$bc = bcdiv($sat, 1e8, 8);
echo $bc;
```

[Рабочий пример](https://3v4l.org/0SLHd)